# How to get compile time type safety when defining a self-removing event Action<...> handler without explicitly typing the full type of the handler?

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.5, type-safety

I have a simple event handler in a class like so:

```
public class Eventable
{
    public event Action<Eventable, TypeB> OnMagic;

    // ...
}
```

I would like to be able to declare a type safe handler by reusing the type of OnMagic, in order to have a reference which can be removed from that same event when a condition is met, like so:

```
static class Program
{
    static T HandlerOf<T>(T _)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var eventable = new Eventable();
        var myHandler = HandlerOf(eventable.OnMagic);
        myHandler = (that, myB) => { eventable.OnMagic -= myHandler };
        eventable.OnMagic += myHandler;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This would stop me from retyping sometimes very long class names in my code and would improve readability, however VS2015 objects with this error:

```
The event 'eventable.OnMagic' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Eventable')
```

Is there an other way to achieve this, to hide completly the type of the event handler, without throwing out type safety?
Thank you.

Comment: `HandlerOf` receives two parameters but you're passing only one. And, what you are trying to do is to raise an event out of the scope of the container class? Because if so, you simply can't do that.

Comment: Forgot to remove that parameter, sorry. I'm not trying to raise the event, I only wish to add an handler to that event.

Comment: Why calling `HandlerOf` for then registering instead of directly registering with `eventable.OnMagic += ...`

Comment: Because it needs to remove itself and thus it needs a reference to remove.

Comment: The `class Eventable` with the field-like event hides the backing field of the event as a kind of private class-level variable (field). It is __possible__ to publish that, for example `public Action<Eventable, TypeB> OnMagicBackingField { get { return OnMagic; } }` but I do not think it is a good idea. See answer by spender.

Comment: Something else: The type `Action<in T1, in T2>` is contravariant in `T1` and `T2`. This can give problems with multicast delegates which lie underneath events. You should consider using a delegate type which is invariant in its type arguments (or is non-generic).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
Action<Eventable, TypeB> myHander = null;
myHandler = (that, myB) => { eventable.OnMagic -= myHandler };
eventable.OnMagic += myHandler;
```

?

After all, you already know the type of `myHander`, so you don't need to go through the contortion of `HandlerOf<T>(T _)` (which *might* be useful for dealing with ***anonymous*** types... I don't see any in your code)

Comment: When the type is Action<SomeHorrendouslyLongClassnameEventable, SomeHorrendouslyLongClassnameTypeB>, it gets difficult to read and I don't think a using-alias-directive would fix that, I want to hide those type names completly.

Comment: I suspect this doesn't compile unless you initialise `myHandler` to some dummy value such as `null`

Comment: @spencer You're right about the anonymous types, but what you're suggesting is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: @gxtaillon Maybe, but at least it's a known paradigm. Adding a layer of indirection to all of this via the generic magic of `HandlerOf<T>(T _)` (if you ever get it working) might make things easier for you, but considerably more confusing for anyone else who visits your code (or even you, in 2 years time...)

Comment: @spencer I understand and I haven't found anything that would suggest it is possible so for now I will *let it go*. What would fix my issue is something like C++'s type aliases. That would allow me to put the real type in a `using OnMagicHandlerType = Action<...>;`, declare `public event OnMagicHandlerType OnMagic;` and cleanly use it as `var myHandler = default(Eventable.OnMagicHandlerType);`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to register an action that when called unregister itself you could do something like:

```
public class Eventable
{
    public event Action<Eventable, int> OnMagic;

    public void Magic(int i)
    {
        OnMagic?.Invoke(this, i);
    }

    public void RegisterMagic(Action<Eventable, int> action)
    {
        Action<Eventable, int> _action = null;
        _action = (_e, i) =>
        {
            action(_e, i);
            OnMagic -= _action;
        };
        OnMagic += _action;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Eventable e = new Eventable();
        e.RegisterMagic((ev, i) => Console.WriteLine(i));
        e.RegisterMagic((ev, i) => Console.WriteLine(i * i));

        e.Magic(4);
        e.Magic(5);
    }
}

Output:
    4
    16
```

Note: I put the `RegisterMagic` in the `Eventable` class just in case this behavior is for `Evantable` objects only. But this can be modified as your needs demmand.